# Python, Pandas - Trouble with code summing counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

Having trouble with code I've written.

The first df 'piv_1' contains a column 'Category' (Either 3.0 or 4.0) and columns ['Start', 'Issue', 'Comments Rec'] containing values 1,2,3...12 (numerical month values representing Jan-Dec).

What I'm trying to achieve in 'df_sum' is, a sum-count of occurrences for ['Start', 'Issue', 'Comments Rec'] from df 'piv_1' by 'Category' (Either 3.0 or 4.0).

First df - 'piv_1' (contains category 3 or 4, other columns month values):

| Category | Start | Issue | Comments Rec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 6 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 6 | 7 | 9 |
| 3 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 8 |

Second df - 'df_sum' (Blank df to populate the count of months for each column, by category 3 or 4):

| Month | Month Value | Category | Start | Issue | Comments Rec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr | 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun | 6 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jul | 7 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Aug | 8 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sep | 9 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct | 10 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nov | 11 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Dec | 12 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb | 2 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun | 6 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jul | 7 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Aug | 8 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sep | 9 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct | 10 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nov | 11 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Dec | 12 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Expected result 'df_sum':

| Month | Month Value | Category | Start | Issue | Comments Rec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 1 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr | 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun | 6 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Jul | 7 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Aug | 8 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| Sep | 9 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Oct | 10 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nov | 11 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Dec | 12 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan | 1 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Feb | 2 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Mar | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Apr | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| May | 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jun | 6 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| Jul | 7 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Aug | 8 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Sep | 9 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Oct | 10 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Nov | 11 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Dec | 12 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I've attempted with the following code:

```
df_sum['Start'] = sum((df_sum[df_sum['Month value']]) == (piv_1[piv_1['Start']]) and (df_sum[df_sum['Category']]) == (piv_1[piv_1['Category']]))
```

I planned to replicate code for each column. That was if it worked...

Appreciate the help.

Kind Regards, Mike.

Comment: Do you want to get unique count of sum (['Start', 'Issue', 'Comments Rec']) columns?

Comment: Hi Lazyer, sum of the total occurrences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also receive sum of the total occurrences by merging parts of the the first table to second table and grouping it by Month, Month Value and Category. How it can look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

#table_1 is your first table
#table_2 is your second table

table_3 = table_2[['Month', 'Month Value', 'Category']].copy()

for i in table_1.columns[1:]:
    temp = ((table_2[['Month', 'Month Value', 'Category']].merge(table_1[['Category', i]],
                                                              left_on=['Category','Month Value'], 
                                                              right_on=['Category',i], 
                                                              how='left')
                                .groupby(['Month','Month Value','Category'], as_index=False)
                                .count()
                                .sort_values(['Category','Month Value'])))
    table_3 = table_3.merge(temp, on=['Month','Month Value','Category'])
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: Love the simplicity behind the logic. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you have df_sum dataframe for all **Category** values and all **Month, Month Value** at each **Category**,

It'll work for that.

```py
from collections import Counter
df_grp = df.groupby('Category').aggregate({"Start":pd.Series.to_list, "Issue":pd.Series.to_list, "Comments Rec": pd.Series.to_list})
df_grp = df_grp.applymap(lambda x: Counter(x))

for category, row in df_grp.iterrows():
    for col in ["Start", "Issue", "Comments Rec"]:
        for key, value in row[col].items():
            idx = df_sum.query("Category == @category and `Month Value` == @key".format(col)).index
            df_sum.loc[idx, col] = value
```

Here is an example. If **df** looks like bellow,

```
Category    Start   Issue   Comments Rec
0   3   5   6   7
1   4   6   6   7
2   4   6   7   9
3   3   6   7   8
4   3   7   8   8
```

**df_grp** is

```
    Start   Issue   Comments Rec
Category            
3   {5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}  {6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}  {7: 1, 8: 2}
4   {6: 2}  {6: 1, 7: 1}    {7: 1, 9: 1}
```

So you can map the value to **df_sum** with **Category** and **Month**(key of dictionary).
I got index with query string with these values and updated with **iloc** function.